# "Cannot set property 'className' of null" erro função Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

No meu template tenho um botão que chama a função de fazer login:

```
<button type="submit" name="entrar" (click)="fazerLogin()" routerLink="/home" class="login" id="login-button">Entrar</button>
```

Eu adicionei uma div para caso o nome de usuário ou senha estiver incorreto, a div aparecer mostrando um toast:

```
<div *ngIf="alertaUsuarioIncorreto" id="toast"><div id="desc"> <i class="fa fa-close" aria-hidden="true"></i> Nome de usuário ou senha incorretos</div></div>
```

Declarei essa variável no meu componente:

public alertaUsuarioIncorreto: boolean = false;

Essa é minha função:

```
  fazerLogin(){
    this.authService.fazerLogin(this.usuario);
    this.alertaUsuarioIncorreto = this.authService.nomeOuSenhaErrados();

    if(this.alertaUsuarioIncorreto = true){
      var x = document.getElementById("toast")
      x.className = "show";
      setTimeout(function(){ x.className = x.className.replace("show", ""); }, 5000);
    }
  }
```

Essa são as funções do meu serviço:

```
      fazerLogin(usuario: Usuario){
        if(usuario.nome === 'renatim@hotmail.com.br' &&
          usuario.senha === '123'){
            this.usuarioAutenticado = true;
            this.router.navigate(['/home']);
          }else{
            this.usuarioAutenticado = false;
            this.alertaSenhaErrada = true;
          }
      }

      usuarioEstaAutenticado(){
        return this.usuarioAutenticado;
      }

      nomeOuSenhaErrados(){
        return this.alertaSenhaErrada;
      }
```

Acontece que a primeira vez que eu clico no botão, retorna a mensagem:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null
    at LoginComponent.push../src/app/components/login/login.component.ts.LoginComponent.fazerLogin
```

A segunda vez que eu clico no botão aparece a mensagem do toast.

Comment: Tem um erro no operador aqui: `if(this.alertaUsuarioIncorreto = true){`.. o correto seria dois `==`.

Comment: Essa tua forma de usar o toaster tá sendo muito trabalhosa, pode me falar qual biblioteca está usando ? eu lembro que eu passava só alguns parâmetros na biblioteca de toaster que eu utilizava e já tinha como usar com facilidade. Eu ia te falar que esse erro é de name, que estava faltando na div, porém, eu vi que no código o ero está sendo mesmo na hora de fazer o replace no timeout do className que tu ta usando